# using USE and Namespace (composer)in sample php file

Tags: php, composer-php, monolog

I have sample PHP file, i run composer install and got Monolog library. 
when I trying their installation guide I get error 500.

When I put the following code in sample file I get error 500 on new Logger row. Maybe I have autoloader? Is it possible to use without it?

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->warning('Foo');
$log->error('Bar');
```

Comment: No, you still need to use the autoloader. Namespacing on its own does not do autoloading.

Comment: You must require the `autoload.php` file that is in the `vendor`directory, and is that file that will allow you to use `use Monolog\Logger` in your script, without requiring the autoload file you will still getting the same error that tell you php doesn't find the Class you are instantiating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using autoloader fixed that 
used that solution :
https://github.com/Nilpo/autoloader/blob/master/Autoloader.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the autoloader. It will be created by composer.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```